# Having trouble with Osmocom source in gnuradio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, software-defined-radio

I'm having trouble running a simple flowgraph with an osmocom source and a qt gui sink. If I run the file with a waveform generator instead of the osmocom source, all is well, the plots appear as they should, no problem.

When the osmocom source is hooked up, everything runs and there is no immediate error message... the gui window just never opens. If I run it from the terminal with verbose output, the output ends with and that's where it hangs.

```
import 'osmosdr._osmosdr_swig' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7f5e0cae23c8>
import 'osmosdr.osmosdr_swig' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f5e0cdda978>
import 'osmosdr' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f5e0cdc9dd8>
```

Not sure what those errors mean but it just hangs there. Eventually it ends up using 100% of CPU and I have to CTRL + \ it to get it to stop. Is it a library maybe in the wrong place that it's not finding?

OS : Ubuntu 18.04
Gnuradio-config-info -version : 3.8.0.0-rc2
gr-osmosdr was installed from the git repo and the gr3.8 branch (which worked for me previously) so as to be ok with gnuradio 3.8. I had initially installed gr-osmosdr from the master branch and instead of doing make uninstall, I deleted the directory. I think installed from the gr3.8 branch, did a make uninstall to see if that maybe might have helped (?) and then reinstalled. No dice.

If there's any more info I can supply, let me know - any and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks!